# Opening file 'with' statment into existing variable

Tags: python

When opening a file in Python, the recommended syntax is:

```
with open(outfile, 'wb') as f:
    pass
```

This creates a local variable `f`, even if I previously declared `f` (in my case, it is `global f`). How can I get it to use the existing variable (the global one)?

Comment: I guess a better approach is to read and parse the file within `with` statement and save its (parsed) contents as global variable.

Comment: The global statement should have worked.  Can you include your actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `global` statement.  The `with ... as f` statement is really just an assignment to `f`, so the same rules apply as with `f = ...`

```
global f
with open(outfile, "wb") as f:
   ...
```

Also, keep in mind that the with-statement will close the file automatically, leaving your global referring to a closed file, which is not useful.

Of course, it's better not to use global variables...